# Float: left blocks not going as expected

Tags: html, css, sharepoint

I am making a SharePoint landingpage with tiles 5x2. Any body any idea how this can happen?

I know it is not the best coded project because of the lot !important. but that is needed in SharePoint.

[image: Tiles]

```
                     <div id="topLeft">
                        <!--CS: Start Web Part Zone Snippet-->
                        <!--SPM:<%@Register Tagprefix="WebPartPages" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=16.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c"%>-->
                        <div id="topLeftWebpart" xmlns:ie="ie">
                            <!--MS:<WebPartPages:WebPartZone runat="server" AllowPersonalization="false" ID="xae7ae0b76116430e84918de3195e8a9f" FrameType="TitleBarOnly" Orientation="Vertical">-->
                                <!--MS:<ZoneTemplate>-->
                                    <!--DC: Replace this comment with default web parts for new pages. -->
                                <!--ME:</ZoneTemplate>-->
                            <!--ME:</WebPartPages:WebPartZone>-->
                        </div>
                        <!--CE: End Web Part Zone Snippet-->
                    </div>
```

CSS:
.image-area-left-top is the container of the images.

```
#topLeft {
        position:relative!important;
        width:47.46%!important;
        top: 30px;
        left: 5%;
        margin:0px;
        float: left;
        padding:0px;
        display:inline-block;
        max-width: 485.984px;
        min-width: 450px;
    }
    #topLeftWebpart{
        width:100%!important;
    }
    .image-area-left-top{
        position:relative;
        float:left;
        width:20%!important;
        height:auto!important;
    }
    .image-area-left-top .image{
        width:75%; 
        height:75%;
        margin-top: 12.5%;
        margin-left: 12.5%;
        margin-bottom: 12.5%;
        margin-right: 12.5%;
```

Comment: My best guess is that some of the images/tiles are slightly different in height, and as a result, some of the floats are being placed on the right edge of tile #3 (Examen Commissie) and tile #6 (Inleverbox).  If these time/images are even 1px taller than the other tiles, that will affect the floats. You can test this by setting a fixed height on `.image-area-left-top .image` and see if this fixes the problem.

Comment: That solved the problem. The .png image was not perfectly square

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see the size of the icons does not seem to be the same. This can cause some issues when aligning. You should force all images to a certain size via css and see if that helped.